# IC buffer like 4066 with 8 or 16 switches

Tags: microcontroller, switches, integrated-circuit, buffer

I have a computer and two monitors. I want to build a device so that I can switch between to monitors. I would use buffers (like 4066) and a microcontroller. Is there any buffer like 4066 with 16 or 8 switches? Because 4066 has only 4 switches and I have to use 4 buffers for each monitor.

[image]

Comment: How many lines are you trying to switch? You may not have to switch all of them.

Comment: @Andyaka The standard monitor port has 15 pins. I think I have to switch them all.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh - Is this VGA or DVI?

Comment: @ConnorWolf sorry I forgot to say. that is VGA.

Comment: Watch out for bandwidth: that device works up to 40MHz, which is only good enough for low resolution video. (It may be easier to just buy a KVM switch for <$20)

Comment: @pjc50 thanks I wasn't aware about the frequency. Do you know an IC to fullfill my need? Btw I know that there is a commercial device for that. But it would be much cheaper if I can make it myself.

Comment: Why does it have to be an electronic switch when mechanical switches will do the job?

Comment: @JImDearden what kind of mechanical switch you mean? Relays?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I was thinking in terms of a very simple rotary switch. You only really need to switch 5 lines (R,G,B,H/HV and V). The grounds are commoned between the input and output connections. Of course you could do the same thing with relays and either operate these with a single switch or drive them with transistor switches controlled by a micro.

Comment: @JImDearden rotary switch is a good idea. But at first could you please tell me how can I use transistor switches? Second, don't I have a frequency problem as other guys said with them?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh - I will put the circuits as an answer below - give me a few minutes to quickly draw it up

Comment: A real KVM will also do some intelligent handling of DID, which you won't get if you just have switches. This may mean your OS fails to detect the monitor, or only detects the properties of the first monitor.

Comment: A colleague of mine once built a mechanical monitor switch with a rotary switch, but the video quality degraded quite a bit. Probably because of poor impedance matching or mutual interference.

Comment: @jippie So do you think I would have the same issue with relay? What are the specifications I have to take into account for the rotary switch, relay or any other mechanical switches?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a collection of various 15-pin VGA schemes: -

[image]

From what I can tell, these are the following lines that probably need switching: -

1. Red video (pin1)
2. Green Video (pin 2)
3. Blue video (pin 3)
4. Horizontal sync (pin 13)
5. Vertical sync (pin 14)

On some devices pins 4, 11 and 12 are no-connects i.e. they do nothing (or are reserved) and 5, 6, 7, 8 and 10 are ground. Pin 9 can be +5V and pin 11 is sometimes "monitor ID"

On other devices pins 12 and 15 look like they perform some kind of SPI serial function.

I would try and make a switch that accomodates 1, 2, 3, 13 and 15 as change-overs but I reckon using a 4066 may not be fast enough - look for a video switch element.

**Important PSU info**
It is possible that you will need an analogue switch that is powered above ground (5V typically) and below ground (-5V) to accodate the AC nature of the video signals.

As for finding a device, [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scds292a/scds292a.pdf) may be suitable as it is a 3-port switch with 7 channels: -

[image]

The blurb says it is "designed for 7-channel VGA signals (R, G, B Hsync, Vsync, DDC Data and DDC clock). By virtue of it operating only from 3V3 I have to assume the RGB signals are biased above GND. This is something you need to determine for sure but it looks promising.

Comment: Perhaps even the two sync signals do not need to be switched: They could be buffered and fed to both monitors at the same time.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I'm hoping someone will explain that - I have a suspicion you are correct but the TI chip accomodates them so maybe it does need to?

Comment: From what I can find out, disabling the sync signals serves only one purpose in KVM switches: For the older monitors which do not have any other mechanism of detecting signal presence, disabling sync starts off the power-saving timer, at the expiry of which the monitor enters a low energy state. Newer (still ancient, since we're talking VGA) monitors use other forms of signal presence detection, either RGB signal delta, or DDS signaling, to initiate low-power sleep mode. That is why some monitors can autonomously enter sleep mode even with an image on screen, if the image never changes.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I guess the OP has to decide what market he's aiming at but quite possibly he should switch the 7 lines that the TI does - it should be backwards compatible even if functionality is lost.

Comment: @Andyaka would you please tell me how shall I connect that to a micro-controller? The datasheet is not telling that clearly or I might not fully understand that. And how shall I connect VGA to this? (Sorry if my question is very basic)

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I'm no expert in what you ask - i'd do exactly what you should do and research TI's database. Your original question gave the impression you knew how to use 4066 devices with a microcontroller - you are expanding the question quite widely now but I can say that the block diagram of the device tells me there are two selection mechanisms that would probably be used together. Input at port A and outputs at ports B and C. The truth table tells this.

Answer (score 1):

*A few circuits to consider.*

Using a 4066 as a change over switch. You need to connect these in pairs so 1 chip will only provide 2 changeovers. The you will also need 2 inverters per chip. For switching 5 lines you require 3 x 4066s and 1 hex inverter.

[image]

Using a mechanical switch - 6 pole change over.

[image]

For relay switches with transistor drivers

[image]

Comment: as Pjc50 said, 4066 has low bandwidth so it is only enough for low resolutions. And Jippie says his colleague has had quality issue with rotary switches. Don't you think I would have the same problem with relays?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh Yes the 4066 is low bandwidth but the 4066 is not the only analogue switch IC on the market. You still require a means of producing a change over switch from an on/off switch. As regards the mechanical switches and relays that will depend on the type and quality of the switch and how you deal with earthing and wiring. Have a look at RF reed relays.